# STS wizard for spring starter missing gradle option

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Until very recently, the spring starter project wizard had a dropdown to select between maven & gradle.  This is now missing and projects initialise with maven by default.

Can someone enlighten me as to why it's gone, and if there is any other automated way of initiating gradle based spring projects in STS/eclipse.  It's not like I can't knock up my own gradle script, but I'm lazy like that.

Thanks

Comment: I am using STS 3.6.2 and I still get the choice to use Maven/Gradle/plain for the guides when using the "Import Spring Getting Started Content" wizard. The Gradle option requires the Gradle tooling to be installed, but that appears as a message at the top of the wizard. Do you see anything different from that?

Comment: I tried the "new spring starter" wizard and it is missing for me as well. I will investigate, it seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Raised a issue here: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3944

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone enlighten me as to why it's gone...

After some investigation I discovered that a recent change in the initializr app (http://start.spring.io) is responsible. The names for the import options in the webservice have been changed and they no longer match those used in the STS import wizard.

The import wizard ignores 'unknown' types (because it doesn't know how to import them). This causes the list of valid type options to become empty and so it is no longer shown by the STS wizard.

See https://github.com/spring-io/initializr/issues/42

I expect the problem to be fixed quickly (will update this answer when its fixed).

*Update*: The problematic changes to start.spring.io app have been reverted and the option should now work again in the STS wizard.

> ... and if there is any other automated way of initiating gradle based spring projects in STS/eclipse.

Yes, there is another thing you can use in the mean time. The "Import Getting Started Content" wizard. The short spring.io guides come in Maven and Gradle flavor. So importing one of those might be a good starting point.